# calling two javascript method for two different event from same tag

Tags: javascript, html

how to call two different javascript method on two different events(onkeyup and onblur) from a same textbox tag.

Basically i need to validate some parameter on press of a key in the textbox and some parameter when the focus moves away from the textbox
i have tried calling the other method from the first method

```
function changer() 
  {
alert('a');
document.getElementById("abc").onblur="change2()";
   }

function change2() 
   {
alert('b');
   }


<input type ="password" id= "abc" value =""  onkeyup="changer();" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do this:

```
<input type ="password" id= "abc" value =""  onblur="change2()" onkeyup="changer();" >
```

Comment: i have tried that too. but in that case both the methods are called on pressing a key.
Insted changer2() method should be called only when the focus moves away from the textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bind function to attach event handler. 
For Example

```
$( "#abc" ).bind( "onblur", function() {
alert('b');
});
```

Comment: i tried this but this binding is not working.Please help

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library? like this <script link="file.js"> </script>

Comment: @user3259812 you can see about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: jQuery is just a library of Javascript. Everything you do with jquery can be done with javascript too. But it will increase line of code. You must be doing any slight mistake. Have you included the library in Head tag?

Comment: Actually jQuery is not allowed to use for me.. If you help me in solving this using javascript. It would be very helpfull

Comment: yeah but javascript creates a lot of mess. To avoid it, use jquery in future. You are Welcome :)

Comment: @YourFriend [When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question) :-D